# Get iPhone calendar events list by date added or some unique id

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, eventkit, ekeventstore

I want to get iPhone's calendar events on the basis of some key or date.
My real purpose is to call a function which get list of events added till now BUT in future when i again call this function it have to give me only newly added events instead of duplicate. till now i am getting events like that

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

if ([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
{
    /* iOS Settings > Privacy > Calendars > MY APP > ENABLE | DISABLE */
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if ( granted )
         {
           // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
           NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
           endDate:endDate calendars:nil];

          // Fetch all events that match the predicate
          NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
          NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",events);
         }
     }];
}
```

but this give me all events in that dates not only new ones.

Comment: `eventIdentifier` property of a `EKEvent`?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but we can't compare this property like that       all events > eventIdentifier    because it is string. In other way i have to persist all old eventIdentifiers and then compare all with every new one, which is not feasible for app. If you have any other suggestion to use this then please tell me